# I cannot execute my class because my class has no attribute 'execute'`?

Tags: python, class

I have my class here:

I have my code here:

```
import logging
import pymysql as pm
import os 
import json

class className:
    env=None
    config=None

    def __init__(self, env):
        self.config=className.get_config(env)
        self.env=env

    def get_config(env):
        cwd=os.getcwd()
        f=open(cwd+"\config_file_name"+".json")
        f_config=json.load(f)
        f.close()
        return f_config

    def DB_connection(env):
         cnxn = pm.connect(
         user="+username+",
         password="+password+",
         host="+host+",
         port="+port+",
         database="+database+"
         )

    def table1():
        cnxn=None
        cnxn=className.DB_connection
        cur=cnxn.cursor()
        table1_INSERT_QUERY="CALL sp_table1_Insert_Daily_Records();"
        table1_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY="CALL sp_table1_Exceptions();"

        try:
            cur.execute(table1_INSERT_QUERY)
            cnxn.commit()
        except pm.Error as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.exception(e)
        else:
            print("table1 insertion query ran successfully, {} records updated.".format(cur.rowcount))
        try:
            cur.execute(table1_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY)
            cnxn.commit()
        except pm.Error as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.exception(e)
        else:
            print("table1 exceptions query ran successfully, {} exceptions updated.".format(cur.rowcount))

        cnxn.close()

def main():
    ve=className
    ve.execute()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am trying to execute my class so it can execute my functions. Basically it creates an exceptions report defining what records are missing from yesterday. This function executes a stored procedure. I get the error saying:

`AttributeError: type object 'className' has no attribute 'execute'`

How do I execute my class and my functions?

Comment: It's really hard to give you an answer here because your code tells me that you have _so many_ misunderstandings about how classes work. That whole `className` stuff everywhere for example doesn't really make sense, your class methods don't take `self`, and where did you get the idea that calling `execute()` is the way to "execute" a class?

Comment: `ve=className(<some env value>)` Note your class blends instance and class variables and methods together and I think it is muddling up things a bit.  Also, by `execute()` did you mean `table1()`?  that kind of looks like an execute() method to me

Comment: In the event that there is an exception with "insertion query" do you still want to attempt "exceptions query"?

Comment: yes i meant i want to execute table1 function...

Comment: in the event there is an error with insertion query, i dont want to attempt the exceptions query

Comment: can someone help me unmuddle my code?

Comment: ah "execute()" was supposed to be a separate function in the guide i am following smh...i changed it to "table1()"

Answer (score 0):

The initial problem is that your class method is `table1()` but you are calling `execute()`. After that things get a little muddles between class and instance.

I would try what this does for you.  Note this is untested.

```py
import json
import logging
import pymysql

class ClassName:
    def __init__(self, env_filename):
        self.env = env_filename
        self.config = self.get_config()

    def get_config(self):
        with open(self.env) as file_in:
            return json.load(file_in)

    def DB_connection(self):
        return pymysql.connect(
            user=self.config["+username+"],
            password=self.config["+password+"],
            host=self.config["+host+"],
            port=self.config["+port+"],
            database=self.config["+database+"]
        )

    def execute(self):
        table1_INSERT_QUERY = "CALL sp_table1_Insert_Daily_Records();"
        table1_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY = "CALL sp_table1_Exceptions();"

        with self.DB_connection() as cnxn:
            with cnxn.cursor() as cur:
                try:
                    cur.execute(table1_INSERT_QUERY)
                    print("table1 insertion query ran successfully, {} records updated.".format(cur.rowcount))

                    cur.execute(table1_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY)
                    print("table1 exceptions query ran successfully, {} exceptions updated.".format(cur.rowcount))

                except pymysql.Error as e:
                    print(f"Error: {e}")

                except Exception as e:
                    logging.exception(e)

                else:
                    cur.commit()


def main():
    ve = ClassName("<path to env file>")
    ve.execute()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: thanks for helping me this worked on executing my python script, now i am sorting through my errors reading the JSON file contents.